# Unable to update rootkit on plesk?

Tags: centos

I am running rootkit on plesk and when running this message shows up:
Mirrorfile /usr/local/psa/var/modules/watchdog/lib/rkhunter/db/mirrors.dat rotated
Using mirror http://rkhunter.sourceforge.net
[DB] Mirror file                      : Failed to retrieve updates.
Failed to retrieve security knowledge base updates from the update server.
The current knowledge base will be used during security scanning.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I have tried trying to run it mannual with rkhunter --update, however, i get the error that this command does not exist, probably because plesk servers are done differently.

I think maybe its a firewall setting? If so what modifications do i need to make in terms of port, ip etc

thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
find / -name rkhunter -print
```

The executable version is here:
/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/modules/watchdog/rkhunter

The generated config file is here: 
/usr/local/psa/etc/modules/watchdog/rkhunter.conf

So `rkhunter --configfile <filename> --update` becomes:

```
/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/modules/watchdog/rkhunter \
  --configfile /usr/local/psa/etc/modules/watchdog/rkhunter.conf --update
```

Answer (score 0):

If the error is that the command does not exist, then you need to find the command -- that's nothing to do with the firewall or the network.  Try "locate rkhunter" to find it.